# VHDL found '0' definition of operator “=”

Tags: vhdl

I am getting this error in my VHDL code :

> found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact
> overloaded matching definition for "="

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity test2 is
Port (clk  : in std_logic ;
    sclk   : out std_logic);
end test2;

architecture Behavioral of test2 is

signal cnt : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
begin

process(clk)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then

  if cnt(2) = "111" then
     
     sclk <= clk ;
   else
     cnt <= cnt+1;
  end if;
 end if;
 end process;
 end Behavioral;
```

Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: `cnt(2) = "111"` The type of the left hand operand is the base type of std_logic while the type of right hand operand is an array type that can't be determined from context. Perhaps you want to have a condition of equality between the entire `cnt` value (an array type) then making the right hand expression the same type.

Comment: As far as 'Where exactly is the problem?'  there's only on relational operator ("=") used in a condition in an if statement found in your code.

Comment: See [VHDL found ‘0’ definition of operator “=”](https://cloudstack.ninja/seong-yong-song/vhdl-found-0-definition-of-operator/) on Cloud Stack Ninja. Found while searching for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

the "cnt" is 3bit signal like (bit2,bi1,bit0). When you write cnt(2) it will mean cnt(bit2), however you compared it with "111".